# torsion part of homology of simplicial complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, homology, simplicial-complexes

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer and let $K$ be a simplicial complex with $N$ vertices. Suppose the $n$-th integral homology group of $K$ is

$$
H_n(K)=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus i}\oplus (\oplus _{p \text{ prime}}\mathbb{Z}_p^{\oplus i_p}). 
$$

Let $p(n,K)$ be the maximal $p$ such that $i_p$ is nonzero.

**Question.** Is there any upper bound of $p(n,K)$, denoted as $f(N,n)$,   that does not depend on $K$? What method shall I use to find such upper bounds?

Comment: Take a look at prop 3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9812171.pdf.

Comment: This is closely related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17771/small-simplicial-complexes-with-torsion-in-their-homology, if not an exact duplicate.