# Small simplicial model for Moore space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I seek for some small simplicial model of Moore spaces $M(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z},n)$. What is the simplest way to construct such? Of course we may take some cofiber of degree $k$ map between spheres, however there is no clever model for such map and therefore for the obtained cofiber.

Comment: There is a simple model for the degree $k$ map between $S^1$, so one can get a reasonable model for higher dimensional spheres by suspending.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17771

Comment: What is a simple model for degree $k$ map between $S^1$? Because if we take non-fibrant model for $S^1$ then there are only two maps $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$.

Comment: SageMath (sagemath.org) has an explicit implementation of $M(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ as a simplicial complex with $2k+3$ vertices. Then as @user43326 says, you can suspend.

Comment: Triangulate the circle as the boundary of a $3k$-gon (that is, $3k$ vertices and $3k$ 1-simplices), and map it to the boundary of a triangle, wrapping around $k$ times.

Comment: Well, you can use $k$-gon for the source, and the model with single 1-cell and single 0-cell for the target.